# Google Plus API get Person by ID

Tags: android, google-plus

In my app I am using the Google API Client with the Google Plus API to get a Google Plus Person's friends.

I want to do this without making the user sign-in.

When a user signs up with my app's account system, they can link their account with Google Plus.

I can store any values in my app's account system, and I have tried storing the Person's ID, which I got like this:

I store the Google Plus Person's ID in my app's account system. Here is how I get the Person ID:

```
Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(
                mGoogleApiClient).getId()
```

I don't know if this is the right approach though, and I couldn't find a way to retrieve the Person later by his ID.

**How can I later get an updated instance of the Person object from Google Plus?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Plus.People.load()](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/plus/People.html#load(com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient,%20java.lang.String...)) takes a list of personIds and returns a `Person` object. Note, however, to do this call:

> This call returns all information in Person, but only for the people specified and for data that is **public in their profiles**.
>
> Required Scopes: [SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/plus/Plus.html#SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN)

Meaning you must have a connected GoogleApiClient with the proper scope and you'll only get back public information.

Comment: thanks for your answer. is their a way I can connect the GoogleApiClient without having the user sign in? Whenever I do connect it, the result.startResolutionForResult() asks the user to sign in.

Comment: Unfortunately no, you'll need the user to be signed in before you can use Google APIs including Google+. Of course, once the user signs in once (and does not specifically sign out) then the sign in for future sessions is done in the background.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Do you have any suggestions for what I should do if the user signs in on a different device. I dont want him to have to sign in again.

Comment: If the user has already logged in with your service once (on any device), then the `onConnect()` method should automatically succeed without user intervention as per [Google+ cross-platform single sign on](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/sign-in#cross-platform_single_sign_on). What are you seeing when you log in on a different device?

Comment: oh... I didn't read that part and I just assumed. Thanks for the answer.